# Change output directory of sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1, scalaxb

I want to change my output directory for some generated files, in this case generated objects from an XSD-Schema.

Here is part of my Build file.

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA,
      settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ buildInfoSettings ++ scalaxbSettings
    ).settings(
      sourceGenerators in Compile <+= buildInfo,
      buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion),
      buildInfoPackage := "hello",
      packageName in scalaxb in Compile := "models",
      sourceGenerators in Compile <+= scalaxb in Compile
    )
```

This code puts my generated files into the below directory:

```
target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/models/
```

How can I change my buildfile to output the files to below instead?

```
/app/models/
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the `sourceManaged` setting key. Any source generator tasks will generally put stuff in the file specified by that setting.

```
source-managed                 - target/scala-2.10/src_managed
compile:source-managed         - target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main
test:source-managed            - target/scala-2.10/src_managed/test
```

Note that the "compile" and "test" values base themselves off of the base "source-managed" value, which is in turn based on the value of `cross-target`, which is based on the value of `target` and a few others.

You can easily change the value of the `compile:source-managed` setting in an sbt build definition with the setting

```
sourceManaged in Compile := file("app/models")
```

If you want to base your setting off of another setting, like the project's base directory, you could use something more like

```
sourceManaged in Compile <<= baseDirectory { _ / "app/models" }
```

Of course, you can find plenty of info on using settings here: <strike>http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings</strike>
*edit:* Looks like that link is dead. It's been a few years so I'm not 100% sure, but this is probably close to what the original link talked about: [SBT 0.13 -
 Build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def.html) or [SBT 1.0 - Build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Basic-Def.html)

Comment: what if a wanted to change the sourceGenerators that are generated may be by eBean?

Comment: Looks like the link is now old :/

Comment: @WillBeason I've edited my answer with a new link that should hopefully cover the same material.

Comment: @WillBeason Here's an archived version: http://web.archive.org/web/20160312162259/http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/More-About-Settings.html